# How to write EXACTLY n bits to UDP packet c++

Tags: c++, udp

As a way to learn my university content, I decided to start writing a networking library in c++11 using UDP and the new threading memory model. Here is my biggest roadblock at the moment.

The size of a byte is platform specific. **Memcpy** copies and writes with respect to the size of a byte on that platform. So how do I go about making platform-agnostic code to write *exactly* **N** bits to my UDP packets? N will typically be a multiple of 8, but I need to be sure that when I deal with N bytes, the same amount of bits are modified, regardless of platform.

The closest I think I have come to a solution is to make a base struct of 32 bits, and access it as groups of 8. E.g.

```
struct Data
{
    char a : 8;
    char b : 8;
    char c : 8;
    char d : 8;
}
```

This way, I know that each char will be limited to 8 bytes. My messages would all be a multiple of 32 - that is no problem (this struct would actually help when dealing with endianness). But how can I be sure that the compiler won't pad the structure to the platform's native boundary? Will this work?

Comment: It's guaranteed to pad the structure to the platforms native boundary (though the padding may be 0 bitsfor 8 bit chars)

Comment: Somewhere I have code for _exactly_ this purpose... I jsut have to find it

Comment: You need to be aware of two things: a) Architectures where a byte has a number of bits different from 8 are ridiculously rare. b) UDP, like the entire TCP/IP suite, doesn't care. It sends data as _octets_. You can therefore only send multiples of 8 bits. If that's not acceptable, don't use UDP.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b039243cddcb4644.  Though it appears there's still bugs.  Also, it should probably be reworked to take an iterator pair instead of a stream.  Also, it seems to be for reading, not writing.  Oh well.

Comment: As the other commenters say, what you seem to want is not possible with UDP.  Nor is it any real problem with any requirement I've ever seen - if you need a bitCount, add into the datagram protocol so that the rx end can mask out the required bits from the last octet.

Comment: My general understanding is that unless you have a custom computer, you can't send N bits, especially where N == 3, 7, 9, 23, etc.  Most computers work with units of 8 bits.  I also believe that the UDP standard is based on 8 bits also.  What are you *actually* trying to solve?

Comment: To expand on the problem - the size of any type is not guaranteed by the c++ standard. uint8_t can actually be stored as 16 bits in memory, or even 32. Just as a bool is padded to 8 bits, a few computers pad everything to 16 bits. I understand that UDP is sent as octets, but how can I force the compiler to write a char or a byte, whose physical size is platform specific, as a single octet? It seems the answer is just "Ignore those stupid computers that store a char in 16 bits. They are extremely rare." Not the best practice when writing a basic library, but meh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is not adequate.  The `char` type is defined as `signed char` (7 data bits, 1 sign bit), `unsigned char` (8 data bits) or `char` by your compiler.

Most computers sending out packets use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` for the octets.

Also, beware of multibyte ordering, as known as Endianness.  Big endian is where the most significant byte comes first; Little endian is where the least significant byte comes first.

Many messaging schemes will pad remaining bits with zeros to make them come out to 8, 16 or 32 bit quantities.

Comment: The C++ standards define a char as supporting, but not limited to, the values you have said above. The only limitation is that the next largest integral type must be equal to or larger than in size. I asked my professor today, and he said that although computers __can__ use different sizes, 8 has been the standard byte size for a long time now, so I just won't support 10 year old computers. Easy. I am aware of endianness, that is why I am explicitly splitting my data into octets. Marking this as answer as it is most helpful.

Comment: Just reread documentation for int8_t - c++11 __does__ guarantee no padding, exactly 8 bits. Wish I could upvote this.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the `#pragma pack(nopack)` directive. As someone pointed out though, you're still going to be dealing with multiples of 8 bits.

char should always be exactly 1 byte, AFAIK although I could be wrong.

Comment: 1 byte is not always 8 bits though. This is only in rare cases as I have found out.

Comment: #pragma pack(nopack) seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I wonder if I should change this to the correct answer... Thomas might be disappointed, I already marked his as the answer.